Mesomeric effect comparison
How do I compare the -M effect due aldehyde and a carboxylic acid? Which will have stronger mesomeric effect?

Nope ronith the link you gave gives -I order and not -M order

@Ronith that is the inductive effect order. Mesomeric effect is different

oh my bad i am so sorry.

An aldehyde would surely have higher $-M$ effect than a carboxylic acid.
Because in a Carboxylic acid there is an $-OH$ group resonating with the $\ce{C=O}$. Hence lowering it's $-M$ effect on the other neighboring group.
Whereas in an aldehyde the $\ce{C=O}$ have more electrophilic nature than carboxylic acid and hence have higher $-M$.

$$Aldehyde$$

$$Carboxylic Acid$$
